# How to reduce site concurrency in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

How can I reduce the load on my site, when multiple users(1000+) are editing the same list?

I understand Co-Authoring can be enabled in Document Libraries. but when it comes to lists, what solutions can I find for allowing multiple editing of list items?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the DataSheet View for the list as the default view allowed me for multiple editing of list items. Also I created a separate view which users can access to see their data and set the filter for this view as "Created By" = [Me]. This helped me out for concurrency management.